# Multi-process map-reduce on python 3.x/Windows 7 running on a single core

Tags: python, linux, windows, mapreduce

I followed this [nice tutorial](https://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/parallel-mapreduce-in-python/) showing how to run multiple map instances as processes. However, on python 3.4.3/Windows 7 x64 a single core is used at any time.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import repeat
import random
import time

def Map(L):
    return len(L)

def Main():
    pool = Pool()
    lst = [random.sample(range(1, 100), random.randint(1, 50)) for i in repeat(None, 1000000)]
    start_time = time.time()
    counts = pool.map(Map, lst)
    print(time.time() - start_time)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

In Linux (vmware ubuntu guest machine) the same script shows 100% busy processors.

Is there any trick to force Windows to run the script with true parallelism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the multi-process feature works as expected also on Windows. However, the `lst` generation takes a lot of time (few times more on Windows than on Linux).

It can be seen in the Task Manager that there are 5 `python.exe` processes when the script is running. At first one of them uses 25% CPU and its memory usage slowly increases. It takes about one minute.

Then 4 other processes take CPU. Here the `pool.map()` is started. However, it lasts only for few seconds. So, it looks like everything is done only in one process.

To see the multi-process in action on Windows it makes sense to reduce `lst` ten times and put some loop into the `Map(L)` function to make it use more time, for example:

```
def Map(L):
    ret = 0;
    for i in range(5000):
        ret += len(L)
        ret %= 50
    return ret

def Main():
    pool = Pool()
    lst = [random.sample(range(1, 100), random.randint(1, 50)) for i in repeat(None, 100000)]

    print("Start")
    start_time = time.time()
    #...
```